# DocumentTermMatrix needs to have a term frequency weighting Error

Tags: r, lda, topicmodels

I'm trying to use LDA() from topicmodels package on a quite large data set. After trying everything to fix the following errors "In nr * nc : NAs produced by integer overflow" and  "Each row of the input matrix needs to contain at least one non-zero entry", I ended up with this error.

```
ask<- read.csv('askreddit201508.csv', stringsAsFactors = F)    
myDtm <- create_matrix(as.vector(ask$title), language="english", removeNumbers=TRUE, stemWords=TRUE, weighting=weightTf)
myDtm2 = removeSparseTerms(myDtm,0.99999)
myDtm2 <- rollup(myDtm2, 2, na.rm=TRUE, FUN = sum)
rowTotals <- apply(myDtm2 , 1, sum)
myDtm2   <- myDtm2[rowTotals> 0, ]  
LDA2 <- LDA(myDtm2,100)

Error in LDA(myDtm2, 100) : 
  The DocumentTermMatrix needs to have a term frequency weighting
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Part of the problem is that you are weighting the document-term matrix by *tf-idf*, but LDA requires term *counts*.  In addition, this method of removing sparse terms seems to be creating some documents where all terms have been removed.

Easier to get from your text to topic models using the **quanteda** package.  Here's how:

```
require(quanteda)
myCorpus <- corpus(textfile("http://homepage.stat.uiowa.edu/~thanhtran/askreddit201508.csv",
                            textField = "title"))
myDfm <- dfm(myCorpus, stem = TRUE)
## Creating a dfm from a corpus ...
##    ... lowercasing
##    ... tokenizing
##    ... indexing documents: 160,707 documents
##    ... indexing features: 39,505 feature types
##    ... stemming features (English), trimmed 12563 feature variants
##    ... created a 160707 x 26942 sparse dfm
##    ... complete. 

# remove infrequent terms: see http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/160539/is-this-interpretation-of-sparsity-accurate/160599#160599
sparsityThreshold <- round(ndoc(myDfm) * (1 - 0.99999))
myDfm2 <- trim(myDfm, minDoc = sparsityThreshold)
## Features occurring in fewer than 1.60707 documents: 12579
nfeature(myDfm2)
## [1] 14363

# fit the LDA model
require(topicmodels)
LDA2 <- LDA(quantedaformat2dtm(myDfm2), 100)
```

Comment: I thought I put weighting=weightTf to make it term-frequency instead of tf-idf. I was thinking that rollup() did not work. But, if I removed rollup, I would get the other error. But quanteda is definitely working great for me. Thanks .

Answer (score 1):

```
all.dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(corpus,
                          control = list(weighting=weightTf)) ; inspect(all.dtm) 

tpc.mdl.LDA <- LDA(all.dtm ,k=the.number.of.topics)
```

Comment: Try adding backticks "`" to help format code in answers 